# add text from textfield into selectbox at javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone point at good tutorial about adding text (by user) from textfield into select list (after clicking a button) with javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/yB9mn/) that shows how you can dynamically add option to a select tag using JavaScript with input from a textfield:

HTML:

```
<select id='myselect'></select>
<input type='text' value='' name='mytext' id='mytext' />
<button value='submit' id='mybtn' name='submit'>submit</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myselect = document.getElementById('myselect');

function createOption(){
    var currentText = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
    var objOption = document.createElement("option");
    objOption.text = currentText ;
    objOption.value = currentText ;

    //myselect.add(objOption);
    myselect.options.add(objOption);
}

document.getElementById('mybtn').onclick = createOption;
```

Basically you have a text field, a button and a select box in the HTML. The submit button is attached with an onclick event that calls createOption function.  The createOption function basically creates an option element and add it into the select box with option text and value equal to the text from the text field.  Using `document.getElementsById` we are able to inject newly created element into the Selectbox and retrive the inserted value from the textfield.

However, if you are looking for a written tutorial this is a good reference to using JavaScript to dynamically populate a form [Creating a Form Dynamically](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript2/createSelectDynamically.htm?)

Comment: The last line of your createOption function should be `myselect.options.add(objOption);`

Comment: @Jamiec yes that is the proper way of doing it thanks for adding mate

Comment: @firestruq thank you good sir have fun coding ;D